# Meaning of NULL definition for a macro in C

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, procfs

I was writing a simple code for accessing my driver data through entry in the procfs. While going through the header file `proc_fs.h`, I came across a macro like:

```
#define proc_create(name, mode, parent, proc_fops) ({NULL;})
```

How this macro functions, since its expansion is `NULL` ?

Comment: @NateEldredge, it has nothing to do with what allowed or not by user of procfs. Check ifdef:s carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The `({...})` is a gcc extension called [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). It is a statement that may use expressions. The last statement used inside statement expression is the value of the expression.

The following returns true:

```
return ({NULL;}) == NULL;
```

> How this macro functions,

The macro `proc_create` with any 4 arguments expands to `({NULL;})`.

> since its expansion is NULL ?

The expansion is not `NULL`, but the characters `({NULL;})`. The expansion of this macro is an expression that evaluates equal to `NULL`.

Comment: I know about statement expressions, but I am curious why they would use it here instead of the simpler `#define proc_create(...) (NULL)`.  Is there any context in which they would be different?  I can't think of one.

Comment: The only thing I see, is that statement expression is not allowed at file scope.

Comment: @NateEldredge, no, it’s semantically different statements. In one case you have function, which returns NULL, in the other simple NULL rvalue.

Comment: The problem this definition solves is to avoid a compiler warning for variables being defined and not used (I am talking about parameters). The correct equivalent is static inline function, but it will take 4 LOCs instead of one.

Comment: Read the rest of `proc_fs.h`: this is an else-case in ifdef.  The other case expects an inline function that returns a value.

Comment: @KamilCuk How does these kind of macro works? Means where are their definitions?